# Add image in arraylist

Tags: wpf, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have to create a WPF app. which collects strings and images in rows. I am not sure if I could use multidimedional array or ArrayList but I cannot figure out how to insert the image into the array. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You want a string with image per row? `public Dictionary<string, Image> MyImages {get; set;}` ... `MyImages.Add("Some String", new Image());`?

Comment: Well yes, but can be used as a database, such as 1 image and 7 string per row?

Comment: well just make the second part of the Dictionary a List by itself then. So if your `Key` is the `Image` then `public Dictionary<Image, List<string>> MyImages {get; set;}` and `MyImages.Add(new Image(), new List<string>(){"A", "B", "C"});`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am not sure if I got it. Lets say, I have row ID 01, the rows should continue with name and one image. So, when I query which image was seleted I get the rest of the row.

Comment: No problem. What is it your confused with? do you need help to understand the usage of this?

Comment: Can I ask you for a simple demo in code? :-)

Comment: Sure. I've added a simple demo of the cases that are very basic, you can download the source from the link in the answer. Do check out the other link to get some better understanding of couple more ways in which you can use a `Dictionary<...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want 1 `Image` against a variable number of `string`'s

your `Image` becomes the `Key` of the `Dictionary` and the `List<string>` it's corresponding `Value`.

```
public Dictionary<Image, List<string>> MyCollection { get; private set; }

...
// Initialisation
MyCollection = new Dictionary<Image, List<string>>();

// Adding new Row
var tempImage = new Image();
MyCollection.Add(tempImage, new List<string>(){"A", "B", "C"});

// Modifying existing row -- for `Key` tempImage we'll add a string "D" and remove string "A"
List<string> existingValues = MyCollection[tempImage];
existingValues.Add("D");
existingValues.Remove("A");

// Removing rows
MyCollection.Remove(tempImage);
```

You can download this sample from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pchjg951fb21qla/WpfApplication18.rar). Hope that clarifies some of the usage ideas. I'd suggest looking at some [Simple Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) to get a better understanding of how you can use `Dictionary<...>` to achieve your requirements.